# How to read in floating-point numbers in Python 3.3.2

Tags: python

I just start with python in school, Im not good but I will try to explain my best. I have a program and I want the program to accept decimals insted of just integers. I dont know how. and can you help me to improve my code? Sorry for my english.. A part of the code is swedish but i think you can understand. If you dont just ask me!
Best regards Jesper

```
a = int(input("Skriv ett heltal (ej decimaltal): "))        
b = int(input("Skriv ett till heltal (ej decimaltal): ")) 
print()
print('Kvadrattabell')
print('=============')                      
print('Tal\tKvadrat') 

for i in range(a, b+1):
print("{0}\t{1}".format(i,i*i))

def funktion():
    a = int(input("Skriv ett heltal: "))         
    b = int(input("Skriv ett till heltal: ")) 
for i in range(a, b+1):                      
    print("{0}\t{1}".format(i,i*i))  
while True: 
    svar = input('Vill du köra programmet igen? (J/N) ') 
    if svar == 'J' or svar == 'j'or svar == "Jajemensan" or svar == "Ja" or svar == "Ja! Gör det": 
    funktion() 
if svar == 'N' or svar == 'n' or svar == 'Nej' or svar == "Nejtack" or svar == "Det räcker för idag!": 
    break
print('Ok då. Tack för idag!')
```

Comment: Start by swapping `int()` for `float()`; integers do not *have* decimals.

Comment: `print("{0}\t{1}".format(i,i*i))` need to be indented

Comment: And `if svar == 'J' or svar == 'j'or svar == "Jajemensan" or svar == "Ja" or svar == "Ja! Gör det": ` could be `if svar and svar.lower()[0] == 'j'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First, integers cannot contain decimals. If you want to have decimals, you'll have to use float types!

Use the `float()` function:

```
a = float(input("Skriv ett heltal (ej decimaltal): "))        
b = float(input("Skriv ett till heltal (ej decimaltal): "))
```

And in your `funktion` function:

```
def funktion:
    a = float(input("Skriv ett heltal: "))         
    b = float(input("Skriv ett till heltal: "))
```

You can read more about types [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) 
Also, about your conditionals, you can make it simple by putting it to a list:

```
ja = ['j', 'jajemensan', 'ja' 'ja! gör det']
#lower it, and check if it's between the valid inputs:
if svar.lower() in ja:
    #do something
```

Hope this helps! If you need more help, just ask me :)

Comment: When I change to float, I get a error message:     for i in range(a, b+1):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>

Comment: Oh sorry.. I don't understand swedish. I'll update my answer soon to fix it.

Comment: Hang on.. can you show me the code? You can update the question.

Comment: @user2916710 Revert back the code to your original. Does it throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace int by float like this in every place where you want to accept input in your code:-

```
 a = float(input("Skriv ett heltal (ej decimaltal): ")) 
 b = float(input("Enter another no: "))
```

similarly in other places.
This is because, integers cannot accept decimals. For more information on built in types, you can check the following link
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_variable_types.htm
and
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html